# Get most visited area from list of coordinates

Tags: c#, sql, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geography

I got a list of coordinates from a GPS tracker in a MSSQL Database.

I would like to get the top 5 most visited places it have been (Lest say within 500 meters).

So far this i what i got:

```
SELECT DeviceTime, LastValidLongitude, LastValidLatitude,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
        (SELECT CAST(
            (SELECT geography::Point(DP1.LastValidLatitude, DP1.LastValidLongitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(DP2.LastValidLatitude, DP2.LastValidLongitude, 4326))) as int
        ) AS DistanceInMeters FROM DevicePositions AS DP2 WHERE DeviceId = 110204443045041
    ) AS DIM WHERE DistanceInMeters < 500) AS NumberWithin500
FROM DevicePositions AS DP1 WHERE DeviceId = 110204443045041
```

DeviceId is the id of the tracker
DeviceTime is the time it have tracked
LastValidLongitude and LastValidLatitude is the coordinates in wgs84

This gives me at list of all the coordinates and the number of the other coordinates within 500 meters.

Example:

```
DeviceTime                LastValidLongitude    LastValidLatitude       NumberWithin500
2012-10-23 17:46:14.000   9.88183333333333      56.9835                 2
2012-10-25 13:45:17.000   9.88183333333333      56.9835                 2
2012-09-14 14:08:16.000   10.0173333333333      57.4558333333333        1
```

But how do i get from here?
I can't just group the NumberWithin500 because if there is 2 places i visited 12 time i will only see one of them.

A solution in C# will also be accepted

Thanks

Comment: You've got a bigger problem than that. Imagine a single land mark. Then draw a circle 500m in radius around it. Any GPS tracker records on circle are 500m from that landmark. But, you may not have any GPS recor for that landmark, and it is possible for None of the GPS records to be within 500m of each other. *(For example you had three points, spread equal distances around that circle.)*  Unless you have the ***landmarks*** recorded as well, infering those central points around which GPS records are located, is not trivial by any means.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. But i can live with that because then it haven't been within 500m of the others. Im not looking for landmark, I just need a top 5 list of the most visited.